# Solving Equation $e^x= \frac 1 x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, numerical-methods

For $x>0$, I want to study and try to solve this equation:

> $$e^x= \frac 1 x$$

without using a graphics-grapher.I am not looking for the exact $x$ that satisfies this equation but the interval that it fits in (e.g.  $x \in (3.1636,4,333)$)

Comment: Short answer: rearrange it to $xe^x=1$ and use its inverse, the [Lambert W function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). The solution is $W(1)\approx 0.56714...$ (and infinitely many other complex solutions). There is no way to express the solution in elementary terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solving $e^x=\frac{1}{x}$ is equivalent to finding roots of $f(x)=e^x-\frac{1}{x}$

A root $\bar x$ of a function has the property that the values of $f$ before $\bar x$ and the values of $f$ after have opposite signs, because the function is continuous and cannot jump from positive to negative without assuming the value $f(\bar x)=0$

Thus I'd propose a table like the following

$
\begin{array}{l|l}
   x & f(x) \\
\hline
 0.1 & -8.89483 \\
 0.2 & -3.7786 \\
 0.3 & -1.98347 \\
 0.4 & -1.00818 \\
 0.5 & -0.351279 \\
 0.6 & 0.155452 \\
 0.7 & 0.585181 \\
 0.8 & 0.975541 \\
 0.9 & 1.34849 \\
 1. & 1.71828 \\
\end{array}
$

looking at the table it is clear that $\bar x$ is in the interval $(0.5,0.6)$

And one can refine its search with another table

$
\begin{array}{l|l}
   x & f(x) \\
\hline
 0.5 & -0.351279 \\
 0.51 & -0.295493 \\
 0.52 & -0.241049 \\
 0.53 & -0.18786 \\
 0.54 & -0.135845 \\
 0.55 & -0.0849288 \\
 0.56 & -0.0350418 \\
 0.57 & 0.0138811 \\
 0.58 & 0.0619005 \\
 0.59 & 0.109073 \\
 0.6 & 0.155452 \\
\end{array}
$

where it is evident that $\bar x\in(0.56,\;0.57)$

Hope that this helps

Answer (score 1):

'Fits in' is very relative. You are searching a zero of $e^x-1/x$ or equivalently a zero of $xe^x-1$. Since $1\times e^1-1 >0$ and for very small $x>0$ you have $xe^x-1 \approx -1 +x<0$ any small enough $x$ and $1$ bracket the solution, e.g. $x \in (0.1, 1)$.

BTW: The exact solution is $x=W(1)\approx 0.56714329,$ where $W$ is the [Lambert-W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) function.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The functions on both sides are continuous on the positive reals. If you pick $x$ very close to zero, you can ensure that the left side is close to 1 but the right side is much larger. If you pick $x$ very large, the left side will be larger still, but the right side will be very close to $0$.

Conclude using the intermediate value theorem using the bounds examined as the end points of the interval containing a point where the two functions are equal.